# Xubuntu 14.04 Automount ext4 USB Stick as root

Tags: usb, mount, xubuntu, automount, ext4

I recently formatted my new Sandisk USB Stick with linux from the default FAT32 to ext4. Unfortunatelly, when Thunar Automounts the stick, it is mounted as root and not as the current user, so if I want to write to it, I need to open a root shell (or sudo).

When I reformat the stick to ntfs, everything works fine...does anybody know, why this happens and how I can change that behaviour?

(I also tried it with Nautilius -> same outcome)

```
user@xubuntu:~$ ls -al /media/user/
total 12
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root 4096 Aug 13 17:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug  6 10:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 13 16:25 usbtest
```

Please let me know, if you need any further information than provided...

**UPDATE**

This is the output of lsusb, that a friend suggestend:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0781 SanDisk Corp.
  idProduct          0x5575 
  bcdDevice            1.27
  iManufacturer           1 (error)
  iProduct                2 (error)
  iSerial                 3 (error)
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: any progress made on this? I'm running xubuntu as well and see my pny usb listed in `lsusb` output `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 154b:007a PNY `

Comment: Unfortunately not really...the only solution I came up with, was plugging in the device, until the /media path is created and afterwards changing the permissions of the folder (and subfolder). From then on, it works for that stick. But as you see, it doesnt answer my initial question to address the default behaviour of ext4 devices. Sorry for the bad news ;)

Comment: Actually I realized afterwards that I was in a special situation. Xubuntu properly detects and mounts a properly formatted usb stick. The problem was that I inserted a bootdisk made in osx. Once I reformatted the disk in osx it was detected just fine under xubuntu. Good luck.